# Failed to get jackson 2.X version from Maven

Tags: maven, jackson

I added the following dependencies and repository to my pom.xml but still can't get the jars downloaded to the maven repo.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <repository>
            <id>opencast-public</id>
            <url>http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
```

I executed maven clean and install after I updated the pom file but still can't get the jars. I was successful getting other dependencies downloaded to my maven repo. Is it because of the repository?

Comment: Once correction: I just checked my local maven repo and I can see the jars have been downloaded to my local repo but I can't import them in my project. I'm trying to import XmlMapper but project can't import the class

Comment: You should wrap the `<repository>` tag in a `<distributionManagement>` tag.  This should be outside of the `<dependencies>` tag.  You also only need `jackson-dataformat-xml` since it includes `annotations`, `core`, and `databind` as dependencies

Comment: I did put them in different tags. The issue is now that I can see them in the maven repo but I can't access them in my code, they are not in the buildpath of the java project.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository tag needs to be placed in this fashion and you need this particular repository to get the jackson jars downl

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
 .
 .
 .
 </project>
```

You can verify avaibility of jar at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.2.2/

Comment: this is awesome, i was looking it for months, anyway i have to download the jars manually and copy it to the m2/repository to make it works, but works anyway,

Comment: @Enrique glad to hear that